# Access list in class from another class

Tags: c#, list, class, datagridview

I know this is asked before, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a class which makes a list from a datagridview. I want to do stuff with this list in another class but I cant't access it. I can access it from Form1.cs like the code underneath. How do I access the list from a random class like I can in Form1.cs?

```
    //Opens the file dialog and assigns file path to Textbox
    OpenFileDialog browseButton = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        browseButton.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm;*.csv";
        if (browseButton.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ExcelPath.Text = browseButton.FileName;
            fileExcel = ExcelPath.Text;
            //SetAttributeValue(ExcelPath, fileExcel);
            //nylp();

            /*
            ////IMPORTERER 10TAB-DATA FRA EXCEL TIL DATAGRIDVIEW////
            tenTabLine.fileExcel = fileExcel;
            tenTabLine.tenTab(tenTabDgv);
            */            

            ////IMPORTERER NYLPDATA TIL DATAGRIDVIEW////
            nylpLine.fileExcel = fileExcel;
            nylpLine.nylpData(nylpDgv);

            ////TAR DATA I NYLPDGV DATAGRIDVIEW OG BEREGNER VERTIKALE ELEMENTER////
            vertElementer.vertBueDGV(nylpDgv, vertElementerDgv);


            GetVertElementasList getList = new GetVertElementasList();
            var TEST = getList.vertList(vertElementerDgv);
            MessageBox.Show(TEST[5].p2.ToString());

        }
        else return;
    }
```

When I try to do something like this I get lot of errors in Error List:

```
class GetKoord
{
    GetVertElementasList getList = new GetVertElementasList();
    var TEST = getList.vertList(vertElementerDgv);

    MessageBox.Show(TEST[5].p2.ToString());


}
```

This is my list class

```
class GetVertElementasList
{


    private List<vertEl> vertElementList = new List<vertEl>(); 

    public List<vertEl> vertList(DataGridView VertElementer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<VertElementer.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            vertElementList.Add(new vertEl
            {
                elNr = (int)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value,
                p1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value,
                p2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value,
                z1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value,
                z2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value,
                heln1 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value),
                heln2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value
            });
        }

        return vertElementList;
    }

}

public class vertEl
{
    private int _elNr;
    private double _p1;
    private double _p2;
    private double _z1;
    private double _z2;
    private double _nylpRad;
    private double _heln1;
    private double _heln2;

    public int elNr
    {
        get { return _elNr; }
        set { _elNr = value; }
    }

    public double p1
    {
        get { return _p1; }
        set { _p1 = value; }
    }

    public double p2
    {
        get { return _p2; }
        set { _p2 = value; }
    }

    public double z1
    {
        get { return _z1; }
        set { _z1 = value; }
    }

    public double z2
    {
        get { return _z2; }
        set { _z2 = value; }
    }

    public double nylpRad
    {
        get { return _nylpRad; }
        set { _nylpRad = value; }
    }

    public double heln1
    {
        get { return _heln1; }
        set { _heln1 = value; }
    }

    public double heln2
    {
        get { return _heln2; }
        set { _heln2 = value; }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I've made it work now except that I get a out of range exception.

class code is:

```
class GetKoord
{
    public GetVertElementasList getList = new GetVertElementasList();


    BridgGeometry obj = new BridgGeometry();

    public void foo()
    {

        var TEST = getList.vertList(obj.vertElementerDgv);
        MessageBox.Show(TEST[2].elNr.ToString());
    }

}
```

In form1 or BridgGeometry as it is called in my project I have which is giving me out of range exception.

```
  GetKoord getZ = new GetKoord();
  getZ.foo();
```

EDIT2:

The code underneath works and gives a message box with some value in list. But the method foo() in class above gives a out of range error.

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        browseButton.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm;*.csv";
        if (browseButton.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {


            ////TESTING////WORKING CODE AND GIVES A MESSAGEBOX WITH VALUE
            GetVertElementasList getVertList = new GetVertElementasList();
            var TEST = getVertList.vertList(vertElementerDgv);
            MessageBox.Show(TEST[2].elNr.ToString());

        }
        else return;
    }
```

Comment: Please remove irrelevant code from the post

Comment: Do they belong to same assembly?

Comment: How about you try reading this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173121.aspx  I think you got some problems with accessing different data types and properties.

Comment: You have to specify the irrelevant code @un-lucky.

Comment: Same assembly? @Anand What's an assembly?

Comment: @Anand Seems to. I dont think he works with different ones

Comment: @Grohl You haven't specified an access modifier which makes it internal by default; which cannot be accessed outside the assembly..

Comment: You mean public class? @Anand If you meen that everything is in the same namespace then yes it is. I tried to make the class public and everything else public in the class GetVertElementasList. This doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Grohl I copied your code and tested it. It works. What errors do you get? Could it be that you get `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @Cataklysim Did it work as is?

Comment: I get Invalid token... Array size cannot be specified etc. I think @Anand is right and I have to make a method. The trouble with that I can't access vertElementerDgv from form1 although I made it public.

Comment: @Anand  yes... Well I put the code in`GetKoord` in the ctor... but it worked... Im checking again, maybe I corrected the error while making the project :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to access the variable directly in the class; which will not work. Try following

```
class GetKoord
{
     GetVertElementasList getList = new GetVertElementasList();
     public void foo()
        {
           var TEST = getList.vertList(vertElementerDgv);
           MessageBox.Show(TEST[5].p2.ToString());
        }
}
```

Comment: With this I can access the list, but I can't access the datagridview vertElementerDgv which is made graphically in form1.cs [Design]. Modifier i set to public.

Comment: BridgGeometry obj = new BridgGeometry();

        public void foo()
        {
            

            var TEST = getList.vertList(obj.vertElementerDgv);
            MessageBox.Show(TEST[5].elNr.ToString());
        }

Comment: Now I get a 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Maybe because you have nothing at TEST[5]

Comment: I'm sure I got values in this position when running code.

Comment: How about checking the count of items in TEST first?

Comment: TEST probably holds 0 items, but why? How can I make the code pass the values in my datagridview to the list in external class than form1?

Comment: Buddy, if TEST holds 0 items how can you expect TEST[5].p2.ToString() to work?

Comment: If I write something like this in foo(): `var TEST = obj.vertElementerDgv;
            MessageBox.Show(TEST.Rows.Count.ToString());` I get count of 1.

Comment: Of course I do not expect it to hold the index value I'm asking for if it's 0, but as I tried to explain I do not understand why it's not holding any values. Here's a [screenshot](https://content.screencast.com/users/fjaosl/folders/Jing/media/8d2c4a20-27ae-48ff-a37f-557a302b7bde/2017-02-03_1303.png) of the datagridview. The foo() method is applied to button1 and it should, in my opinion, return more than one count.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seemed to worked. My code for you and @Anand
No Errors, except for empty Lists. But thats because I didn't fed it any information. So, there shouldn't be a problem.

@Grohl maybe try my code and comment where the error is displayed. This should be the most easy way to find the problem.

`TestClass` which represents `class GetKoord`

```
namespace TestForm
{
    class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            DataGridView tmp = new DataGridView();
            GetVertElementasList getList = new GetVertElementasList();
            var TEST = getList.vertList(tmp);

            MessageBox.Show(TEST[5].p2.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The `GetVertElementasList`

```
namespace TestForm
{
    class GetVertElementasList
    {
        private List<vertEl> vertElementList = new List<vertEl>();

        public List<vertEl> vertList(DataGridView VertElementer)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VertElementer.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                vertElementList.Add(new vertEl
                {
                    elNr = (int)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value,
                    p1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value,
                    p2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value,
                    z1 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value,
                    z2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value,
                    heln1 = Convert.ToDouble(VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value),
                    heln2 = (double)VertElementer.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value
                });
            }

            return vertElementList;
        }

    }
     //Some other stuff
}
```

Last but not least. the code from the button click event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView tmp = new DataGridView();
        GetVertElementasList getList = new GetVertElementasList();
        var TEST = getList.vertList(tmp);

        MessageBox.Show(TEST[5].p2.ToString());
        TestClass tmpClass = new TestClass();
    }
}
```

To @Grohl EDIT2:

It hurts to see that you are trying to read data without checking if there is any. In such cases, check!

Like this:

```
if(TEST.Count() >= 3)
{
    MessageBox.Show(TEST[2].elNr.ToString());
}
```

It should debug at be smooth at runtime. I think your problem is getting the data.
Make sure you load the needed data and check if it isn't `null`.

Comment: @Grohl are you sure that in `MessageBox.Show(TEST[2].elNr.ToString());`  `TEST[index]` got enough? Set a breakpoint and look at the count propertie. Try to not use hard coded index numbers.

Comment: Seems like it is reading the datagridview before values are written to it? I'll make an EDIT 2 to show the problem and what I do not understand.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The problem is getting the data from datagriview. Sorry for don't explaining this properly. Do you know how I can pass the data from the datagridview?